# Perl shorthand for if statement

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have the following code in Perl:

```
next if ++$count == 1;
```

which should be the equivalent of

```
if (++$count == 1) {
    next;
}
```

Is there a way to run `next;` if I add more conditions? (i.e. if ++$count is equal to 1 or greater than some other value?

Comment: try "and"-ing them together in one line.  Disclaimer, I haven't done perl in 13 years.

Comment: Wouldn't it be OR? A number cant be both equal to 1 and greater than some other value

Comment: whatever the logic calls for :)

Comment: @Bijan "A number cant be both equal to 1 and greater than some other value" 1 is equal to 1 and greater than 0.

Comment: It wasnt in my code but $count is initialized to 0. So the ++$count would make it become 1 right away

Answer (score 9):

I think something like

`next if ++$count == 1 or $count > $other_value;`

ought to just work. It's quite dense though, and reliant on the side effect of the increment, and the order of precedence

I'd be tempted to add parentheses and move the increment away

```
$count++;
next if ($count == 1) or ($count > $other_value);
```

Comment: Just note that with `or` as soon as a `true` value is found the others won't get evaluated since any true value in `or` renders the whole thing as `true`.

Comment: @Zuzlx that's OK though, the RHS of the `or` don't introduce any side effects in any of the cases ?

Comment: @Zuzlx so long as the `++` is on the first command, it won't matter.

Comment: @Bijan yes, but it's better not to include modifiers in complicated expressions, because of these kind of traps, which is why I moved it. I think it's a good point to beware of.

Comment: I dunno what else to say than, bugs bugs bugs.  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test the *incremented* value of `$count` for two separate conditions then it would be best to increment it in a separate statement rather than testing once against `++$count` and once against `$count`

So your code would be

```
++$count;
next if $count == 1 or $count > $some_other_value;
```